# Variable in sed command

Tags: sed

I can't get this sed command to work.

```
remote_file_path=$(tac $local_file_name | sed -nr '1,/$file_name/ d; /^\\/ { p; q }')
```

If I replace the single quotes with doubles, it breaks the rest of the command and I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated address regex
```

Basically what I'm doing is using tac to search through a file backwards so that I can locate the preceeding line that starts with a backslash and assign it to the variable remote_file_path.

THank you

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables. Try searching around, there are hundreds of similar questions here.

Comment: I did put in my post that if I use double quotes it breaks the rest of the command. Then I get this error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated address regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes don't expand variables. Double quotes do, but if the filename contains a slash (or some other character special to sed), it can break the expression. You can use a different regex delimiter (e.g. `\=$file_name= d`), but only if you're sure the file name can never contain it (or other special sed characters, e.g. a dot).

Use a real language with variables, variables in shell are just macros; for example, you can use Perl:

```
f=$file_name perl -ne 'next if 1 .. /\Q$ENV{f}/; print, last if /^\\/'
```

- `\Q` makes all the special characters in $f literal (see [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta)).